# Python: How do I generate a keypress?

Tags: python, keypress, popen

I am opening a process (with os.popen() ) that, for some commands, detects certain keypresses (e.g. ESC - not the character, the key).  Is there a way to send keypress events to the process?

Comment: How is the other process reading keypresses?  Reading from stdin?  ncurses?  X11?  Windows messages?  DirectInput?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like [`Pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect).  It's been around a while, and there may be a better alternative, now, but it will let you do what you want.

As far as I know, there is no easy way to do that kind of thing with os.popen or the commands in the `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way would be to start the process in it's own shell.
something like os.popen("sh command")

Answer (score 0):

What platform is this on?

You may have to actually feed events into the event loop, if it's running on Win32.